# eslint - Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

When i try to run the application by `npm start`

```
Failed to load plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '.eslintrc.json': Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": ["plugin:react/recommended", "airbnb"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".ts", ".tsx"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["src", "node_modules"]
      }
    }
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "off"
  }
}
```

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.9",
    "@types/scrollmagic": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.21",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.14.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "eslint": "^8.10.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally solved it by downgrading eslint.

```
 "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "eslint": "^7.32.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a known `typescript-eslint` [issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/15149) that may appear upon upgrading to `eslint` version 8.0.0, which has some breaking [changes](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/3738). Some comments on that first link indicate resolution by downgrading to eslint version 7.32.0.

If I understand correctly, `typescript-eslint` **v4** does not support `eslint` v8, but `typescript-eslint` **v5** [does](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/3738#issuecomment-940122046). So you might try either *downgrading* your eslint to version 7.32.0 or *upgrading* your typescript-eslint to v5.